# why my ajax minifier not merge javascript file

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have 3 java-script files in my project, I use ajax minifier to concate them with command,

```
copy bootstrap.js+space.txt+jquery-1.8.2.js + space.txt + one.js + space.txt many.txt
ren many.txt many.js
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\AjaxMin" many.js -o common.js
```

It creates common.js file, but when I add it in my page, it gives javascript error says,
$ is not defined, but I have already include jquery-1.8.2.js in common.js...

in my page I include it in head section with code,

```
<script src="js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

when I do same for css file, it works...

can anyone give me good solution...?

Comment: how do you include jquery inside common.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `jquery` before including `common.js` like,

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in yours javascripts files do something like :

```
;(function(window, $, undefined) {

    // your code and functions here

})(window, window.jQuery);
```